# Transform dolfin::Matrix into Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am coding in C++ and use Fenics for finite element discretization. Now I would like to transform a dolfin::Matrix into a Eigen::Matrix. How can I do that?

I have done something similar for vectors:
I have given c_vec which has the type:

```
std::shared_ptr<dolfin::Vector>
```

Then I have used

```
std::vector<double> c_vec_new;
c_vec->gather_on_zero(c_vec_new);
```

(I am computing parallel). And then I could create a Eigen::Vector by

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> c_vec_eigen(c_vec_new.data(),c_vec_new.size());
```

Is there an easier way?
How do I transform a dolfin::Matrix into an Eigen::Matrix?

I would be very grateful for help!
Moerni